# Tracking approximate values of specific percentiles

Tags: algorithms, statistics

At the moment I use [HdrHistogram](http://hdrhistogram.org/) to track approximate distribution of a stream of values. But I don't really need all percentiles, just three of them. Is there some algorithm to track specific percentiles? Precise algorithm with two heaps isn't feasible because of number of values.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Note that while [Questions about how a particular piece of software … works aren't science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), concepts behind that software or a particular use may be: be specific about `specific percentiles`.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worthwhile to look at streaming algorithms for the median and see if they can be adapted.